# Error with Steam

Tags: steam

I've just installed Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with these commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
 sudo apt-get install steam
```

After the update is finished, I opened it and it said `glXChooseVisual failed`. How can I fix it?

[image: Error screenshot]

**EDIT :**
After restarting PC, program opened like this and I think it stuck here:

[image: Steam starting windows]

**EDIT 2 :** I couldn't solve this problem, I just installed Steam with Playonlinux software. So, can say that problem is solved for me.

Comment: What is your GPU?

Comment: Nvidia GTX850M.

Comment: Are you using Nouveau or Nvidia Proprietary?

Comment: I'm using Nvidia Priprietary. Actually, It opened after I restart the PC. But there is another problem. I'm updating the post.